# Auto populate select fields in a PHP form with a drop down selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and CI. I created a form contain 2 drop down that retrieves data from MySQL.

I have `tb_sekolah` table with `id`, `kota`, `nama`, `provinsi` and `status_sekolah` as column names.

I did show data from `kota` in `tb_sekolah` table in the first dropdown. The problem is, I would like to show data from `nama` in the second dropdown. If user select data in the first dropdown then the second dropdown show data from `nama`.

Example: Column `kota` has data such as yogyakarta, bantul, and sleman. Column `nama` has data such as `sma 1 yogyakarta`, `sma 3 yogyakarta`, `sma 1 sewon`, `sma 1 sleman`. If user selects `yogyakarta` in the first dropdown then the second dropdown only shows `sma 1 yogyakarta` and `sma 3 yogyakarta`

Comment: thanks vrohhh, i'm not smart enough to speak english
hehe

Comment: would be good if you could vote or accept answer !

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you will have to disable the second dropdown and then have to write a jquery/javascript function which invokes on change event ie, when something from the first dropdown is selected.

```
$('#select').on('change',function(){

    var value = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url goes here",
        data: value
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#secondDropdown').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#firstDropdown').html(data);
    });

});
```

the url must point to a controller function which would query and send the related dropdown options in html format.

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
        $string = $string.
        "<option value=$option->name>$option->name</option>"; 
}
```

Comment: can i use query to show data from table database in jquery ?

Comment: NO! You can't directly query in jquery, you can use $ajax, $get or $post depending upon requirement. use jquery documentation for better understanding. The url in ajax points to a function, that function processes and sends a reply. The second part of code tells you how to form the response.

Answer (score 0):

that's a common issue i encounter with a lot of frameworks, the easiest and simple way to overcome this is to make a string containing the HTML for a list that is populated by the sql this my personal script here i have used in LARAVEL feel free to use it.

```
$string = "<option value=></option>";
foreach ($categories as $category_item)
{
        $string = $string.
        "<option value=$category_item->name>$category_item->name</option>";
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to show data in the other dropdown. if you have some data in the first dropdown from categories, you select the option and then how do you show in the second dropdown.

Comment: you would have to use JAVA script and auto_focus i don't have a way to  do it in PHP sorry, but search on tutorials on how to use auto_focus and i am sure you will be able to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) First of all you have to do an ajax call after selecting values from first dropdown. I would use jQuery but feel free to use any at your convenience.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'path/to/url/get_nama',
    dataType : 'json',
    method : 'get',
    data : {
        kota : $("#first_dropdown").val()
    },
    success : function(data){
        //add data to second column here
        $("#second_dropdown").empty();
        for(d in data['nama']){
            $("#second_dropdown").append("<option value='" + data['nama'][d].id + "'>" + data['nama'][d].nama + "</option>");
        }
    },
    error : function(){}
});
```

In your php model code:

```
function get_nama()
{
    $kota = $this->input->get('kota');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, nama FROM tb_sekolah WHERE kota = '{$kota}'");

    $data = array(
        'nama' => $query->result_array(),
        'success' => TRUE
    );

    print json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: url : 'path/to/url/get_nama', what is that mean ?
example : 'localhost/ci/sign_model/get_nama'
is that right bro ?
correct me if i'm wrong
thanks